# Can I /release and /renew DHCP of a router?

Tags: router, lan, dhcp

My current setup is as follows:

There is a router the WAN goes into (R1). There is one more router (R2) connected to it and two switches.

```
  WAN
   |
   | 
  R 1
   | 
   | ----- R 2
   | 
   | ----- Switch 1
   | 
   \-------Switch 2  --- XP          Wireless printer
```

In order to connect the wireless printer I want to replace the normal switch 2 by a device which I call R3.

R3 is not a router. It is a multi function device which combines switch, WAP and router.

I want to replace switch 2 by this device, connect the normal wired computers (aka the XP host) to the switch part and connect the wireless printer to its WAP. I want to do this in such a way that the printer can be used by all computers in the network.

I read about it, it is possible, but there is an IP conflict. The guide I used (which is here: http://www.tomsguide.com/us/how-to-two-priv-lan,review-193-2.html) suggests using /release /renew option (since one of the computers I plug into R3 is XP). Would it renew the IP for R3 or for the computer only?

If it's computer only I'm not sure it will suffice, since I plan to connect more devices to R3. What should I do then?

Answer (score 1):

Let me draw your network as I understood it:

```
  WAN
   |
   | 
  R 1
   | 
   | ----- R 2
   | 
   | ----- Switch 1
   | 
   \-------Switch 2  --- XP
```

I assume that Router 1 is connected via its WAN port to the WAN and that the three other devices (R2, Sw1, Sw2) are connected via its regular ports.

Since you have end devices connected to the switch I assume that R1 has DHCP enabled for the internal network. **That means that the ancient XP computers gets its IP, subnet etc from R1.**

Now it you replae switch 2 with a router then tou have two options:

1. Use the router as a dumb switch. Connect both the computers (XP) and R1 to the internal LAN ports and disable the DHCP server on R3. It will simply act as a switch.  (Possible a faster switch, or one with optional additional capabilities. e.g. when R3 is not a router but an all in one device with routing and wireless and ....)
2. Are you can use the router as an actual router. In that case connect R3's WAN port to R1 and the XP host to the R3 LAN ports. Note that this will be a separate network. Set up its IP range **different** from the range handed out by R1.

If you did not select a different IP range then R1 and R3 will be handing out the same IP numbers. And for SOHO devices the default seems always to be 192.168.0.0/24.  (Same BTW holds for R2, make sure all three are on different networks).

As to DHCP release. If the XP host was booted before and had an IP from R1 then it will try to use this again. It *should* get an answer from R3 stating 'nope, do not use that, use this IP instead'. Using ipconfig /release (cq /renew) should help with that but should not be needed. Windows should detect on its own when the networm cable is unplugged and check the network settings when they get plugged back in. And I do not see how you could change Switch 2 with a router without unplugging....

Two more things:
1) What are you trying to reach? What is the goal?

If all computers in the internal network are allowed to see each other then it would be so much simpler to let R1 handle everything and just use R2 and R3 as dumb switches. Much less management headache.

2) The article you linked to is likely 20 or more years old. It still meantions class C networks which we have not used in decades. These days all is CIDR.

Comment: You drew my set up perfectly. I like both options you presented, but have questions to both:
1. Can devices (and I mean network printer) just connect to it wirelessly?
2. setting up different IP range - how do I do that? I'm afrad I will be forced to use that solution due to the small number of lan ports (the router has 1 wan and 4 lan and I need to plug 4 lan devices which leaves me with just wan slot available. Or can I extend it even further by pluging switch to R3?)

Comment: Let me just explain that I need to replace the switch with router because I need wireless for printer so that all the devices could see it and I have a wireless router and a non-wireless switch.

Comment: Might want to add that to the original post. Use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/979226/edit) link for that.

Comment: I have. I also used your solution 1. But when I connect devices via wifi all the computers start having connectivity issues. The Internet works and then it doesn't. Can the network be overloaded with devices?

Comment: A wired network can be overloaded, but that depends on the devices (e.g. cheap SOHO devices, managed switches, which broadcast services are running on clients, ...) etc etc.  But for wireless all bets are off. Wireless can break in oh so many way. Esp. if the 2.4GHz band is used.